# Flutter Local Notifications: MissingPluginException When Triggering Notifications Based on Condition

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

I've been trying to implements a local notification functionnality on my flutter app that trigger a certain local notification when a condition is fullfilled.

Here is the class that handle the notification

```
class NotificationServices {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  final AndroidInitializationSettings androidInitializationSettings = const AndroidInitializationSettings('');

  void initialNotification() async {
    InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: androidInitializationSettings
    );
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);

  }
  void sendNotification() async {
    AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      "channelID",
      "channelName",
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.max,
    );
    NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidNotificationDetails
    );
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0, // Notification ID (unique for each notification)
      'Your Notification Title', // Replace with your notification title
      'Your Notification Body',
      notificationDetails
    );
  }

}
```

When fullfilling the condition a create a new NotificationServices and call the `initialNotification()` and `sendNotification()` to send the notification,  However I got this error

```
Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method show on channel dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications)
E/flutter ( 5220): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:308:7)
E/flutter ( 5220): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5220): #1      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show (package:flutter_local_notifications/src/flutter_local_notifications_plugin.dart:192:7)
E/flutter ( 5220): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5220): #2      showNotification (package:retain/pages/notificationsFonctions.dart:129:3)
E/flutter ( 5220): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5220): #3      Localisation (package:retain/pages/notificationsFonctions.dart:71:3)
E/flutter ( 5220): <asynchronous suspension>
```

I've tried to change the flutter local notification package version and added

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

In the main function